# Directshow.net don't detect all mics in Windows 7

Tags: c#, windows, audio, directshow, directshow.net

I'm having problems with the Directshow.net library and Windows 7.

In some PC (only if in Device Manager > Controllers Sound, video, listed: "High Definition Audio Device") only detect 1 mic when Skype, MSN, and Recording Devices, lists at least two; when executes this code:

```
Filter audioDevice = null;
if (capture != null)
audioDevice = capture.AudioDevice;
```

"audioDevice" only have the first mic (internal mic or rear mic), and don't retrieve de second mic (front mic -jack-) or vice versa.

Someone has solved or know another library to capture Video and Audio from C#??

Answer (score 2):

There is little to solve here. DirectShow.NET uses DirectShow, which in turn uses [Audio Capture Filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317587%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which uses legacy audio APIs to capture audio. Skype instead uses [WASAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371455%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), latest and greatest audio capture API in Windows Vista+ (falls back to older APIs in Windows XP-).

There is only one workaround available: to write proprietary audio capture filter backed by WASAPI.

Comment: mmm, thanks for you answer,Do you know where I can start looking to create the Audio capture Filter?

Comment: You are unlikely to be able to do it in .NET since APIs are native. You need Windows SDK, and [samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375468%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) from there. `PushSource` is typical sample for those who want to inject data into DirectShow pipeline.